# React-Router & MobX - Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-router, provider, mobx-react

I am trying to access my store from every component page I have, so I followed the following tutorial in order to connect React Router & MobX.

http://frontendinsights.com/connect-mobx-react-router/

However, I am facing a problem at **The MobX way – Provider component**.

This is the code exmaple:

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import usersStore from './stores/usersStore';
import itemsStore from './stores/itemsStore';

const stores = { usersStore, itemsStore };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I tried to do the same in `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, hashHistory, Route, IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'
import App from './webapp/App'
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import Dogs from './components/pages/Dogs'
import Cats from './components/pages/Cats'
import Provider from 'mobx-react'
import RootStore from './webapp/stores'

const store = RootStore

render((
  <Provider rootStore={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/dogs" component={Dogs}/>
          <Route path="/cats" component={Cats}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

However, because of `<Provider/>`, I am getting an error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Why am I getting that? It should work doesn't it?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: If you wrap the `<Router>` inside a `<div>` does that solve things?

Comment: I will give a try but why would it makes it work?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a web app, **react-router-dom** should be used.

Here is the correct way to inject store with `Provider` https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observer

I wrote a solution for your code without using decorator, so it supports create-react-app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, Observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const myStore = observable({
  home: 'Home',
  cat: 'Cat',
});

const Home = () => (
  <Observer 
    inject={stores => ({ myStore : stores.myStore })}
    render={props => (<section><h1>{props.myStore.home}</h1></section>)}
  />
);

const Cat = () => (
  <Observer 
    inject={stores => ({ myStore : stores.myStore })}
    render={props => (<section><h1>{props.myStore.cat}</h1></section>)}
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider myStore={myStore}>
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><Link to="/home">HOME</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/cat">CAT</Link></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/home' exact component={Home} />
              <Route path='/cat' exact component={Cat} />
              <Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

All the components are in App.js file. There is no change in default index.js from create-react-app.

**Note:**
The another way to doing this, it's to simply create a singleton class for the store and use `export default new Store()` to make it available to all components. The class itself doesn't have to be observable, but its properties do.